# Is it incorrect to use eval() within this function? Can I accomplish the same functionality without it somehow?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function I can use to test all for falsy values, keeping it concise since it will be run quite often serverside.

```
function is_falsy(val){
   val = eval(String(val).toLowerCase());
   return !!val;
}
```

I wonder if there's any way it could be done shorter, or what the possible negative implications of using `eval()` might be. JSBIN tells me it is "evil".

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/UZibUFE/1/edit)

Comment: Explain the original task. It's not clear what you want to achieve with this function

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what this function would do, but that may be me

Comment: @Pekka 웃: it's 2 of us. PS: he probably wants `'false'` to be falsy

Comment: Please don't do this. Imagine any arbitrary piece of javascript inserted into the middle of your code, then imagine what possible damage it could do. Now you know why `eval` is evil.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Test if a value is one of the falsy types of data. Maybe undefined could come in as a string, maybe as actually undefined. I want to determine if it is a falsy value that's could be a bit disguised due to its datatype

Comment: @MikeW Imagine somebody typing into their dev console.

Comment: @thomas: "Maybe undefined could come in as a string" --- and how `"undefined"` string is falsy?

Comment: Can you define what values you are regarding as falsy? Your definition seems to differ from the generally accepted one

Comment: @Pekka웃 If it comes in as the string `"undefined"`, I still want it to evaluate to false.

Comment: @thomas: `if (val == 'undefined') return false; return !!val;`

Comment: @thoas That sounds like a bad idea. What if your value is actually a (completely unrelated) string `undefined`? Or `false`? Or `!true`? Or `!1`? Why would falsy values ever come as a string in the first place, isn't that a sign that something went wrong somewhere else? This is begging for unexplained bugs later

Comment: Please explain the downvote. It's something I need to do, and just because it is attempting to solve a scenario that isn't ideal, doesn't mean it's a bad question. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess people disagree with the basic idea

Comment: @thomas: 10 minutes passed and you haven't explained **WHAT** you need to do PS: didn't downvote either

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, it's not ideal; It's just that I have to test for these values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Assuming* that `val` is a *string* that represents a JavaScript *literal* then we can take advantage of the fact that the only [*false-y* values](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) in JavaScript are:

- 0 (+ or -)
- NaN
- the empty string (`''`) or (`""`)
- null
- undefined
- false

Thus, ignoring edge-cases (like `0.0`) we could write it like so (a lower case can be performed as in the original code):

```
function is_falsey_literal (lit) {
  if (['""', "''", "null", "undefined", "false", "0", "NaN"].indexOf(lit) >= 0) {
    return true;
  }
  // Ideally there are more checks on numeric literals such as `-0` or `0.0`.
  return false;
}
```

If needing to check a full *expression* then `eval` may "work" and is likely more practical when compared to writing a full JavaScript-in-JavaScript parser. For instance, in the above, the input string of `(void 0)` will be "true" although it evaluates to `undefined` which is definitely not a truth-y value.

Of course, perhaps the original data can be written/consumed such that there is no need for such a construct at all ..

Comment: What do you mean by "JavaScript-in-JavaScript" parser?

Comment: @thomas Rewriting `eval` without using `eval` :)

Comment: But how would you _do_ that?! :D

Comment: @thomas By writing a lexer, parser, and evaluator for the relevant portion(s) of the ECMAScript language .. or, doing something like [JS.JS](http://sns.cs.princeton.edu/2012/04/javascript-in-javascript-js-js-sandboxing-third-party-scripts/): "js.js is a JavaScript interpreter in JavaScript. Instead of trying to create an interpreter from scratch, SpiderMonkey is compiled into LLVM and then emscripten translates the output into JavaScript." :)

Answer (score 2):

There should never be any need to treat a string containing `false` or `undefined` as falsy. Doing so is inviting false positives (or false negatives) on possibly completely unrelated data.

Imagine what else would be treated as "falsy":

- `!true`
- `!1`
- `!!true`

it's begging for mysterious bugs in your application further down the line.

The program flow should make sure that an `undefined` value actually arrives at your testing script as a literal `undefined`, not a string `"undefined"`.

Comment: It's just the situation. I didn't design it, and I don't have control over architecture elements farther up the hierarchy.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: it's a great combination isn't it: a messy architecture and a messy implementation :-)

Comment: @zerkms well, it does happen... :)

Comment: @Pekka 웃: not in our wonderworld with bug-free code and unicorns ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to test is falsy, then the below is enough.

```
function is_falsy(val){
   return !val;
}
```

If you want to test whether a string is falsy value like `'false'`, then

```
function is_falsy(val){
   try {
     return !JSON.parse(String(val).toLowerCase());
   } catch(e) {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: `'false'` for OPs code acts as a falsy value, while not with yours PS: -1 not mine

Comment: `JSON.parse(String(val).toLowerCase())` would fail for any string that isn't a valid literal type

Comment: I would just enumerate all exception values like user2864740 in their answer did